# Setup PHP on Ngnix and Ubuntu server

Tags: php, node.js

How can I install php on my server and use it for my websites? I am on nginx. I installed mysql and php using apt-get on ubuntu. Also can I use php and node.js on the same website? I do not know where to start and don't have code to post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot use `PHP` and `node.js` on the same website (you also would not really need to).

To install `PHP` on `Nginx`, follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
```

Edit the line that says `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` in the file `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`, changing the `1` to a `0`.

Edit the line that says `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` in the file `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, changing the `127.0.0.1:9000` to `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`.

Restart PHP-fpm (`sudo service php5-fpm restart`)

When you want to use `PHP` on a website, in the config file, under server, add this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Just as a personal preference, stick with `node.js` over `PHP`. It will pay off in the future. ;)

Comment: Not really sure. If necessary, use a combination of joint PHP and Node on one site it is possible.  It is only necessary to competently distribute upstream between different locations in the nginx config. Situations where this may be necessary very often.

Answer (score 0):

1.`sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5 php5-fpm nano`

*If you have apache2 installed, type `sudo service apache2 stop` and then `sudo apt-get remove apache2`*

2.`nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

3.Uncomment both listen lines to make nginx listen on port 80 IPv4 and IPv6.

4.`service nginx reload`

5.`nano /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` and set  `cgi.fix_pathinfo` to 0.

6. `service php5-fpm reload`

7.Place all your files in  `/usr/share/nginx/html/`

More Information at https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-fpm-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-14.04-lts-lemp